# Stealing tokens from client PC on a domain controller?

Tags: metasploit, token

I'm trying to hack my domain controller lab. I created a lab with 4 PC's and 1 servers (2012 R2). I succeeded in hacking one of the PC's via the EternalBlue exploit.
So when I run whoami i got : NT AUTHORITY\system

When I'm trying to steal the token for process running by domain controller admin :

[image: Process task list]

CDAC/Administrator is for my domain controller .. and I used the following command in metasploit : steal_token PID ... I successfully get the privileges but what I need to do is to add a new user on that domain controller and connect to that user via SMB and dump `ntds.dit` to get all the hashes for all PC's on the domain.

Can any one explain how to do that please ?

Comment: i solve it by : net user evilboss password123 /add /domain
net user evilboss password123 /add /domain
\
C:\Windows\system32>net group "Domain Admins" evilboss /add /domain ..... but when i try to use exploit/windows/smb/psexec
 i got this error : - Exploit failed [no-access]: Rex::Proto::SMB::Exceptions::LoginError Login Failed: The server responded with error: STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE (Command=115 WordCount=0)
[*] Exploit completed, but no session was created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's solved. I just add another user name and add that user to domain group. Command's I used:

```
net user heyheyhey password123$ /add /domain 
net group "Domain Admins" evilboss /add /domain
```

And then I connect via rdesktop and I used powershell payload to get meterpreter on domain controller server.

Comment: ok i'll edit it